# My fontawesome and bootstrap icons dont show up in azure

Tags: azure, express, icons, font-awesome, bootstrap-icons

I use express and html to run an html file, and normally the icons show up very good if i run it myself on my own port, but if i for some reason run it on azure, the icons just show up as little boxes, and i dont see anything

[this is how it shows normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1m2s.png)

[this is how it shows in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LIPC.png)

I dont know how to fix, because i didnt write the code for the dashboard myself, it was a template
I asked some AI Bots, searched on google too, but couldnt get an answer

Comment: "run it on azure": What service are you using?

Comment: for my service,  i use azure

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

use cdn likn's for fontawesome and bootstrap icons. if another issue then please explain it.

[fontawesome cdn link's](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)

[bootstrap cdn link's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)